# Protect SVN content?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I installed SVN on a Windows 2008 server, everything works like it should, except that everybody knowing the structure and the server IP can check stuff out. How do I protect the SVN content? I am using TortoiseSVN as client. Do I use the authz file for that?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using svnserve (the svn:// protocol) or are you hosting it over a web server? Apache or IIS? There are authentication mechanisms for both.

Comment: As a general rule: password-protecting networks resources is done server-side, not client-side ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

authz is for apache-hosted subversion. You need to create a users file in your repository's conf directory with `user = password` pairs and then reference it from your svnserve.conf file. From [the online book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.auth):

> ### Create a users file and realm
>
> For now, the [general] section of svnserve.conf has all the variables you need. Begin by > changing the values of those variables: choose a name for a file that will contain your > usernames and passwords and choose an authentication realm:
>
> ```
> [general]
> password-db = userfile
> realm = example realm
> ```
>
> The realm is a name that you define. It tells clients which sort of “authentication namespace” they're connecting to; the Subversion client displays it in the authentication prompt and uses it as a key (along with the server's hostname and port) for caching credentials on disk (see the section called “Caching credentials”). The password-db variable points to a separate file that contains a list of usernames and passwords, using the same familiar format. For example:
>
> ```
> [users]
> harry = foopassword
> sally = barpassword
> ```

Comment: Did that and it still lets me check out without asking for a password. What is the users name that tries to check out or read? I referenced the user file from the conf file (password-db = passwd).

Comment: Hmm - worked for me last time I tried it. Can I check you're restarting svnserve to make sure it picks up the configuration changes, and not specifying some other configuration file on the command line?